Oracle UTL_FILE: how to preserve zero before decimal point
Oracle 19c
I have a table with cost_value NUMBER column.
When I write the value (0.429) out into a file, it appears as .429
How do I preserve zero before decimal point?
Eugene

One option is to export a string instead of a number. How? By applying the to_char function with appropriate format mask.
For example:
SQL> create table test (col number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (0.459);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (13.2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (1520.325);

1 row created.

Then you'd
SQL> select col,
  2         to_char(col, '999G990D000') col_string     --> something like this
  3  from test;

       COL COL_STRING
---------- ------------
      .459        0.459
      13.2       13.200
  1520.325    1,520.325

SQL>


Thank you for quick reply. Your solution works for most of my data, but the following select to_char(2192.926, '999G990D000') from dual returns 2,192.926, but I need 2192.926. I just need to be able to preserve zero for numbers less than 1. The rest of the numbers should have only decimal separator.

You're welcome. Just remove the "thousands" separator (G) from format mask.
